# In "spring-data-elasticsearch" 4.0.4.RELEASE, how to convert SearchHits to Page?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In `spring-data-elasticsearch` 4.0.4.RELEASE, `ElasticsearchRestTemplate`'s `queryForPage()` methods are deprecated, need to use `search()` instead, which return `SearchHits` instead of `Page`.

So, how to convert `SearchHits` to `Page`, or how to still get results as `Page`?

I have searched via google, and checked official doc, and checked source code, still don't know the best way, any help?

Answer (score 4):

The `Query` parameter to be passed into the `search()` method can have a `Pageable` set for the request. To wrap the returned `SearchHits<T>` object in a `SearchPage<T>` you just can do

```java
SearchPage<T> searchPage = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, query.getPageable());
```

Comment: Ok, so in that case, wondering why the API not just keep `queryForPage()` to make it easier.

Comment: the `QueryForPage` methods return  `AggregatePageImpl` objects which are deprecated. So we would have needed to add another `queryForSearchPage` method to return a `SearchPage`, increasing the number of methods in the API. Instead we choose to clean up the API in this part.

Comment: With above code, seems `SearchPage` include all hits, so not suitable to use ...

Comment: do you have a `Pageable` set on the query?

Comment: I did more test, the code from answer does create a page, doesn't include all hints. But in the result both `content` and `searchHits` contains the page of items, that's redundant. So, for now `queryForPage()` seems to be a better choice.

Comment: what do you mean by hints? Do you mean hits? If the query is paged, only the requested number of hits is returned. The `SearchHits` has a collection of `SearchHit` objects and that is returned by the `SearchHIts.getSearchHits()` method that is available in `SearchPage`. That the same list of objects is returned by `getContent()` comes from the fact, that `getContent()` is a method that must be implemented by a `Page`(`Slice`) implementation.

Comment: Yes, I mean `hits`. My above comment means `SearchPage` has 2 copy of the page data. So, If I return `SearchPage` directly, it would be redundant. Thus seems need to create another page-like instance to contain only 1 copy of the data to return to frontend. And, that's exactly what `queryForPage()` did.

Comment: Thanks for notifying that duplicate list; indeed there are two lists, but they are containing the same entity objects. But two different list objects - we will need to fix this. But even when the list objects are the same, `searchPage.getContent()` and `searchPage.getSearchHits().getSearchHIts()` will both be available. I think we should have a look at the implementation of SearchPage to fix this up.

Comment: Hey, @P.J.Meisch, thanks for your solution it really helped me. Btw, I've also raised a question here in regards to mock ElastisearchOperations, maybe you have a better idea about it? This is the question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589066/how-to-mock-elasticsearchoperations-spring-data-elasticsearch-v-4-0-3-when-uni

Comment: You can unpack searchHits first, and then manually construct a new Page object：

`List<xxx> list = (List<xxx>) SearchHitSupport.unwrapSearchHits(searchHits);`

`final Page<xxx> page = new PageImpl<xxx>(list, query.getPageable(), searchHits.getTotalHits());`

`return page;`

Answer (score 0):

From:
`SearchHits<Parcel> searchHits = operations.search(query, xxx.class);`

You then:

```
List<xxx> content = (List<xxx>) SearchHitSupport.unwrapSearchHits(searchHits);
return new PageImpl<>(content, query.getPageable(), searchHits.getTotalHits());
```