# How to mock ElasticsearchOperations (spring-data-elasticsearch v.4.0.3) when unit testing

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mockito, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on a project that uses Spring 2.3.3, spring-data-elastic-4.0.3, ElasticSearch 7.9.0 and mockito-core 3.3.3

I'm trying to mock ElasticsearchOperations when writing unit tests, this is the Service I would like to test (where it's used ElasticsearchOperations):

```
@Service
public class SearchByLabelServiceImpl implements SearchByLabelService {
     private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate;
    
        public SearchByLabelServiceImpl(ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate) {
            this.elasticsearchTemplate = elasticsearchTemplate;
        }
    
    public SearchPage<TagResponse> searchByLabel(String query, List<String> labelsToExclude, boolean shouldIncludeDescription, Pageable pageable) {

    ....
    enter code here
    var result = elasticsearchTemplate.search(nativeSearchQuery, TagResponse.class, IndexCoordinates.of(tagIndexName));


}
```

And this is the Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public class SearchByLabelServiceImplTest {


private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate = mock(ElasticsearchOperations.class);

    private SearchByLabelService searchByLabelService = new SearchByLabelServiceImpl(elasticsearchTemplate);

    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void shouldReturnTheTagsBasedOnSearchRequestIncludingDescription() {

   ...//Arrange

when(elasticsearchTemplate.search(queryArgumentCaptor.capture(), eq(TagResponse.class), IndexCoordinates.of(tagIndexName))).thenReturn(searchHitsResponse);

        var searchResponse = searchByLabelService.searchByLabel(testSearchQuery, testLabelsToExcludeList, true, PageRequest.of(1, 1));

....

//Assertions 

}
```

And the error I get is this one:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11.0.5+10-LTS
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.5+10-LTS
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 10.15.7


Underlying exception : java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetaData not present

    at com.optum.genesis.tag.service.SearchByLabelServiceImplTest.<init>(SearchByLabelServiceImplTest.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:226)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetaData not present
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: strange. `org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetaData not present`, this class comes from the `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch` library which should be on the classpath

Comment: Thanks @P.J.Meisch for your answer. Do you know if there is any way to explicitly include it? somehow?

Comment: can you run the test from the commandline with `mvn test` or `gradle test` whatever build system you are using?

Comment: Yes, I can run it from the command line using `mvn test` and I still get the same error. But I've noticed that It warns me about some version mismatch when compiling it: `WARN org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo:64 - Version mismatch in between Elasticsearch Clients build/use: 7.6.2 - 7.9.0` not sure if that might have something to do with the missing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.3 which was built with Elasticsearch library 7.6.2, but during the runtime you are providing Elasticsearch 7.9.0.

Elasticsearch had a little breaking change in their code between 7.6 and 7.9:
The class `org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetaData` was renamed to `org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetadata` - please notice the change from *D* to *d* in *Metadata*.

So what can you do? Why do you need to use the Elasticsearch libs in 7.9? If you cluster is running on 7.9, you could probably still access it with client libs from 7.6.
Or you update your application to use Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1 which was released yesterday.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I appreciate your help. I finally upgrade it to use Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1 and the error was gone after fixing some of the deprecated classes.

Comment: You saved me a ton of time by pointing to a small change from D to d. Really small I would say unnoticeable :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the ElasticsearchOperations in a new class you could create (eg ElasticsearchOperationsWrapper) where you would expose the methods you need and in your code, wherever you invoked ElasticsearchOperations replace it by ElasticsearchOperationsWrapper and then you could mock it normally. ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).